# UIimagepicker controller image only selection

Tags: iphone, image, uiimagepickercontroller

I have to give functionality to select photos by the user. I have used this:

```
ipc.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

Now I have to restrict user to select only photos and i want videos to be not displayed on the list. Or somehow user should not select video at all. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 19):

basically what you're trying to do is to set the "media types". and luckily for you imagePicker has a property just for that called "mediaTypes". :) which receives an array of media types to show for selection.

even luckily-er this is the default behaviour of ImagePicker is to show only image types.

but if you really want to make sure you can do this:

```
[imagePicker setMediaTypes: [NSArray arrayWithObject:kUTTypeImage]];
```

and don't forget to add at the top of the file... :)

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
```

but really, i think we can trust apple when they say it's they're default behavior... :)

Comment: You will also need to link MobileCoreServices.framework `targets > build phases > link binary with libraries > + > MobileCoreServices.framework`

Answer (score 18):

You will get a compiler warning about incompatible pointer types (at least in XCode 4) when adding kUTTypeImage to an NSArray. However, kUTTypeImage is a CFStringRef, and according to the CFString documentation, a CFStringRef is compatible with NSString *. Therefore, to make the compiler happy, cast kUTTypeImage to an NSString *:

```
picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
```

Answer (score 2):

UIImagePickerController defaults to only image. Just avoid specifying media types the it will display only images to select.